# JMESPath to combine nested array with nested key value

Tags: jmespath

The input JSON is:

```
$ cat multiple.json
[
  {
    "postfix": [
        "aaa",
        "bbb",
        "ccc"
    ],
    "prefix": "one-"
  },
  {
    "postfix": [
        "aaa",
        "bbb",
        "ccc"
    ],
    "prefix": "two-"
  }
]
```

The output I want is:

```
$ cat output.json 
[
  "one-aaa",
  "one-bbb",
  "one-ccc",
  "two-aaa",
  "two-bbb",
  "two-ccc"
]
```

So far I managed to create:

```
$ cat multiple.json | jp "[*].map(&join('', ['pre-', @]), postfix)[]"
[
  "pre-aaa",
  "pre-bbb",
  "pre-ccc",
  "pre-aaa",
  "pre-bbb",
  "pre-ccc"
]
```

When I replace the literal string `pre-` with the key `prefix`, I get:

```
$ cat multiple.json | jp "[*].map(&join('', [prefix, @]), postfix)[]"
null
```

I tried replacing `prefix` with `$.prefix` and `@.prefix`, but to no avail:

```
$ cat multiple.json | jp "[*].map(&join('', [$.prefix, @]), postfix)[]"
SyntaxError: Unknown char: '$'
[*].map(&join('', [$.prefix, @]), postfix)[]
```

```
$ cat multiple.json | jp "[*].map(&join('', [@.prefix, @]), postfix)[]"
null
```

My version of `jp` is:

```
$ jp --version
jp version 0.2.1
```

So how to solve this problem in JMESPath? I now how to solve it in python, but I am interested in the pure JMESPath solution.

Comment: There is no such thing is JMESPath as a parent operator, but in the `join`, the object you have is the array inside `postfix`, thanks to the `map`. So, that definitely won't be achievable this way

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was already afraid that it might be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

As of to date, no solution exists in the current version of JMESPath to solve this particular problem.